# How to stop automatic scroll when reloaded through fancytree library?

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I am using a library of js fancytree to which I want to populate the data on reload, but along with this I'm encountering an issue i.e. my page is scrolling which I don't want. Here is my line of code

```
$("#tree").fancytree("getTree").reload(tree_data);
```

I want tree_data value to reload. But, not want my page is scroll. Is there is any alternative available? Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance.